# How to tell if the following functions are one to one (without calculator)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x)= 1/x-2$

$g(x)= x^4+3$

I'm confused on how to solve it. Can someone on here explain how to do it?

Comment: Start from definitions what does it mean for a function to be one to one?

Comment: Incomplete question --- [the title is not the first sentence of your question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)

Comment: One can only determine whether a function is "one to one" (or did you mean $1-1$? injective) if  one knows the domain for which the function applies.  We can certainly choose a (fairly restricted) domain for which the functions shown are one-to-one, but it is unclear if that is relevant to you.

Answer (score 0):

A function is one to one if different inputs go to different outputs. Therefore if you can find two different $x$ values are having the same f(x), your function is not one-to-one.

Your first function is one-to -one because if $x_1 \ne x_2$ then $1/(x_1-2) \ne 1/(x_2-2)$

your second function is not one-to -one.

I let you find an example of those different $x$ values with the same $f(x)$ values.

Answer (score 0):

One to one means that if $f(x) = h(w)$ then $x = w$.  It is not possible for $x \ne w$ but $f(x) = h(w)$.  To not be one to one means it is possible for $x \ne w$ but $h(x) = h(w)$.

If $f(x) = f(w)$ then $\frac 1x -2 = \frac 1w - 2$ so $\frac 1x = \frac 1w$ so $x = w$.  So it is one to one.

If $g(x) = g(x)$ then $x^4 +3 = w^4 + 3$ so $x^4 = w^4$ so $\sqrt[4]{x^4} = \sqrt[4]{w^4}$.  So $|x| = |w|$ and $\pm x = \pm w$.  So $x$ does not have to equal $w$.  We could have $x = -w$ where $x > 0$ and $w < 0$  and then $g(x) = x^4 + 3 = (-w)^4 + 3 = w^4 + 3 = g(w)$.  So $g$ is not one to one.

(I'm not sure how to prove these *with* a calculator to tell the truth...)

Comment: do you mind making the steps for the second equation a bit simpler? I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove it by contradiction.
For g(x), suppose it's not one to one which means there exists x0 satisfying $y1=g(x0), y2=g(x0), and  
  y1 \neq y2\\$.
Then we have $y1 \neq y2,\\
                    x0^4+3 \neq x0^4+3,\\
                        x0^4 \neq x0^4$, which is obviously false. So our assumption is false.

As the comment said, ask yourself the definition of one to one function.

Comment: Thank you for your help!